# How do I recognise Pokemon Go battle warnings?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've read that in Pokemon Go battles yellow sparks give warning that your opponent is about to use it's Charge Move. I do see the wording 'x used x' but fail to recognise these sparks. Does anyone have a better description or image of what I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the sparks indicate that the enemy is about to attack, either with a normal or a charged attack.

Once you see the words "x used x", this means that the next attack will be a charge attack and so you should look to the sparks to see when to dodge it.

I've noticed that if you're attack is not very effective or super effective, the text saying the enemy used a charge move will be delayed, so keep that in mind. This is likely to be a bug and not intentional.

The yellow sparks can be seen on the edge of the screen, it flashes for a short time and the best time to dodge is right after the flash. You can see the yellow 'sparks' in the image below:

[image: pokemon go gym battle attack warning indicator, yellow sparks]

Alternatively, some pokemon's charge move has quite a long animation, so for these pokemon it can be really simple to see if it is going to be a charge move or not as the next attack.